# Input auto focus not working on mobile browsers on angular app

Tags: angular, typescript

I developed multiple inputs and after one input filled cursor will auto focus to next input, it's working fine on pc and laptop browsers.

my code:

```
document.getElementById(ne)?.focus()
document.getElementById(ne)?.scrollIntoView()
```

**.focus()** and **scrollIntoView()** both are not working

Tested devices: **Android google chrome**

Anyone have solution for this it may helpful.

Comment: Have you tried putting it in ngAfterView? Try the console to see what stage it loads. Maybe it loads before the HTML

Comment: No any errors or alerts in console

Comment: I mean console.log(1) at your "focus" code. To see HTML and JS load order

Comment: yes.  (keydown)="keyCheck($event.code,'num2') ? '' : null" this keydown event didn't fired

Comment: Did you mean the focus() feature is in the keydown? Have you tried putting it in ngAfterView?

Comment: yes .focus() method not working, in ngAfterViewInit() also

Comment: Please provide your full code.